# Do Two-wire Full Duplex Data Signal Cause Collison at atomic Level

Tags: particle-physics, waves

Can the transmitting and receiving signal travel in the same wire in Full Duplex (FDD)?

If yes, will there be any collision at atomic level?

If yes, how this phenomena can be explained?

Comment: Welcome to physics.SE. It is preferred if only one question is asked per question. Furthermore, the first question is an engineering question, not a physics question, and should be asked at engineering.SE.

Comment: In engineering this phenomena is explained by using Fourier Analysis and the discussion on what happens at the atomic level is discarded. Hope I get someone to assist me to understand about this phenomena.

Answer (score 1):

On a physics level, the the answer is, that the signal travelling through a conductive cable is an electromagnetic wave. And even electromagnetic waves around wires do not interact strongly (and thus can pass through one another).
So in principle you can use a single wire for full duplex.

The diffuculty is then to separate the signals at the ends of the wire. One method is to use different carrier waves for the two signal directions (then the Fourier stuff you mentioned in the comment applied), but that is rather inefficient bandwidth wise (as you have to modulate the signal slowly compared to the carrier frequency). Another problem is to supress reflection at the wire ends to prevent noise. So again, the main challenge, is engineering, not physics. (And the cost for this added complexity is usually more than that of an extra strand copper).

---

About collisions: A conductor does not, conduct electrons (or atoms) ballistically! The signal you receive at the end of the wire is not the electrons pushed in on the other end, the drift velocity of electrons in wires is on the scale of µm/s (depending on the material). If this were the signalling mechanism the internet would be useless.

The signals travelling through the wire is actually the electromagnetic field guided by the wire. To illustrate this fact:
A signal representing a bit in a 1Gbit/s Ethernet wire is just about 60cm long (two twisted pairs are used for one datastream, the baudrate is therefore around 500MHz, $c/500\,\mathrm{MHz} \approx 60\,\mathrm{cm}$, $c$ is of course just an approximation of the signal velocity in the cable, it will be somewhat slower). So there are a few bits of information *stored in the wire*. And this information is not encoded in movement of electrons (this would be damped after a few millimeters) but in the travelling electromagnetic field around the wire!

As the em fields travelling in opposite directions interfere, the electrons do simply not move in opposite directions where there is a signal travelling from the left and one from the right, but do not move at all (as the resulting field will cancel out locally). But this interference will not hinder the propagation of the signal!

On a side note: Considered even more microscopically the "collisions" of electrons actually do something. Electron-electron interactions and interactions of electrons with impurities contribute to the electrical resistance of the wire and therefore are responsible for the damping of the signal over long distances (but this already happends for a single signal travelling throgh the line).